# Check if Azure VM name exists before deploying arm template

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-powershell

I am trying to use Azure powershell to get VM name (Eg: `demovm01`, where the VM name is `demovm` and the suffix is `01`.

I want to get the output and automatically append a new suffix of `02` if `01` already exists.

Sample script to get vm name:

```
$getvm = Get-AzVM -Name "$vmname" -ResourceGroupName "eodemofunction" -ErrorVariable notPresent -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
if ($notPresent) {
    Write-Output "VM not found. Creating now"
}
else {
    Write-Output "VM exists."
    return $true    
}
```

I want to be able to inject this new vm name to an arm deploy to deploy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it. Will increment until no VM is found and use a simple `-replace` to inject to your json file. Will also return all thr VM values that are already present in Azure

```
$i=1
$vmname_base = "vmserver"
$VMexists = @()

do {
    #invert int value to double digit string
    $int = $i.tostring('00')
    $getvm = Get-AzVM -Name "$vmname_base$int" -ResourceGroupName "eodemofunction" -ErrorVariable notPresent -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    if ($notPresent) {
        Write-Output "VM not found. Creating now"
        Write-Output "VM created name is $vmname_base$int"
        #Set condition to end do while loop
        VMcreated = "true"
        #commands to inject to json here. I always find replace method the easiest
        $JSON = Get-Content azuredeploy.parameters.json
        $JSON = $JSON -replace ("Servername","$vmname_base$int")
        $JSON | Out-File azuredeploy.parameters.json -Force
    }
    else {
        Write-Output "VMexists."
        # Add existing VM to array
        $VMexists += "$vmname_base$int"
        # Increment version, ie. 01 to 02 to 03 etc
        $i++
    }       
} while ($VMcreated -ne "true")

return $VMexists
```

Comment: what if vmserver01 was found? I want it to loop to the next iteration vmserver02 to see if that exists ...etc.

Comment: I've just removed the return,  but that's what the `$i++` increment does in the `else` block.

Comment: Do you need to return if the VM exists? If so you're else block could look more like

Answer (score 0):

Your command could be like below, the `$newvmname` is that you want.

```
$vmname = "demovm01"
$getvm = Get-AzVM -Name "$vmname" -ResourceGroupName "<group name>" -ErrorVariable notPresent -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

if ($notPresent) {
    Write-Output "VM not found. Creating now"
}
else {
    Write-Output "VM exists."  

    if($getvm.Name -like '*01'){
        $newvmname = $vmname.TrimEnd('01')+"02"
    } 
    Write-Output $newvmname
  return $true
}
```